# Windows crashes when connect to VPN Server over Bluetooth DUN

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I have a 3G SIM Card in my phone which I can use to connect my notebook to the Internet via bluetooth dial-up. When I connect to the Internet this way, I have full access to the Internet. But if I try to connect to VPN over it, Windows crashes. If I connect to my phone to my computer via cable, this does not happen. It must be a problem with my notebook bluetooth driver. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define "crash" - Is that a blue screen, freezes up, application error?

Since it seems to be related only to VPN connections, you should look at the VPN software as well. If you are using something like a Cisco VPN client, make sure you have the most current, updated version.

Comment: OS: Windos7, Phone: Samsung Hazel, I am using windows builtin featuires for bluetooth, dial-up and VPN. I am using PPTP connection. I have no issue if I use DSL. When I connect to Internet through bluetooth, once connect to VPN server, blue screen.

Answer (score 0):

[This forum thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/4d4134b9-7033-42af-95ce-45cc8dfe6581) has some people with similar issues; some suggest checking your antivirus software. Are you running any? In addition, that and other forums point to bugs in the Shrew Soft VPN client.